# Bootstrap Datepicker duplication when selecting month - Meteor 1.4

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, datepicker, meteor-blaze

I'm using rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker package from atmosphere.js to get dates on a input="text" tag using Meteor 1.4, but when i use it to change months it stucks on the screen permanently, and it duplicates itself (saw it through dev tools) when i click the input field again.

I changed the size of the screen to see if it duplicates, and the plugin creates this on the screen;[Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSYm4.jpg)

My code looks like this on the html template (Blaze)

```
<div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Plazo</span>
   <input class="form-control" id="date" name="fechaentrega" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" type="text" required aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
</div>
```

And the JS file looks like this;

```
Template.checklist.rendered=function(){
  $('#date').datepicker({
   format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
   language: 'es',
   startDate: new Date(),
   todayHighlight: true,
   weekStart: 1,
   container: 'body',
   orientation: 'bottom',
   autoclose: true
  });
}
```

This "checklist" Template is being imported to a MainLayout Template who is in charge of displaying the main info of the page, if it affects it in any way.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the exact issue ? After selecting the month, it doesn't close ?

Comment: Exactly, after you switch months, and pick a date it will not close itself, and the calendar stays on the screen, even if i switch templates using dynamic templates.

Comment: Hmm... can you check by removing "required" from the input field.

Comment: required removed... same problem, it stucks on the screens and duplicates when i inspect the page with dev tools. (i used this plugin on another project and it didn't had problems with it).

Comment: I changed the plugin for tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker , and it works perfect, even when its a different one its probably from the same root project, so i will never know if it was a bug in the datepicker plugin.